# jQuery Mobile doesn't apply style on dynamic checkboxes and can't clicked

Tags: css, json, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm trying to refresh the number of checkboxes that has been appended in fieldset tag when clicked at menu tab footer. The 1st tab visit is okay but after that, all checkboxes can't be checked anymore. I have been modified my code several times but it doesn't work. Sometimes they can be checked but without style applied. Sometimes they can't be checked but have style applied.

I have tried `.controlgroup('refresh');` and `.checkboxradio("refresh");` but none of them are working. I have look at most of similar questions but they're not helping me solve this problem. May be I put the code in the wrong place?

For `.checkboxradio("refresh");` the console always log this error.
cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method `'refresh'`

This is my original HTML and JS

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
     <div id='delete_wrapper'>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" id='deleteButton'>Delete</a>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" id='deleteAllButton'>Delete All</a>
     </div>
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id='checkboxes_wrapper2'>

     </fieldset>
 </div>
```

And this is my JS

```
runfirstDelete = true;
$('.delete_tab').click(function(){
$("#checkboxes_wrapper2").children().remove();
    var dataIndex;
    var dataName;
    for(var i in localStorage)
    {   
        dataIndex = JSON.parse(localStorage[i]).index;
        dataName = JSON.parse(localStorage[i]).name;

        if(runfirstDelete){ // This for 1st time visit, It's working okay.
            $("#checkboxes_wrapper2").append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+dataIndex+'" id="checkbox'+dataIndex+'" value="'+dataIndex+'"/><label for="checkbox'+dataIndex+'">'+dataName+'</label>');
        }
        else{ //if not, trying to insert embedded style in element
            $('#checkboxes_wrapper2').append('<div class="ui-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="'+dataIndex+'" name="'+dataIndex+'" id="checkbox'+dataIndex+'"><label for="checkbox'+dataIndex+'" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="a" data-mini="false" class="ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">'+dataName+'</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></label></div>');
        }
    }
    runfirstDelete = false; //Then indicate that it's not 1st click on tab
});
```

Comment: for `else` you dont need to add all classes since they will be automatically enhanced by JQM.Add only `<div class=ui-checkbox>` and for `<input>` add type, value, name, id and label and try again..dont add `classes` nor `span`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are adding new elements, there will be no jQuery Mobile widgets to augment them, so trying to call their `refresh()` method will indeed fail.

A simple way of telling jQuery Mobile to "catch up" with new markup is to trigger the `create` event on a container element:

```
$("#checkboxes_wrapper2").trigger("create");
```

Comment: Thank you. I added 

$("#checkboxes_wrapper2").trigger("create").controlgroup('refresh');

And it's working perfectly now. :)